# cpprest server, need a way to change the CHUNK_SIZE value at runtime

Tags: c++, curl, casablanca

Our application normally transfers data (using HTTP GET) of several hundred megabytes, the default 64 Kb chunk size seems too small for optimal download rate. Changing the value to 5 Mb can reduce download time of 2 Gb data from 2minutes to 28 seconds.

The demo code, which just allocates the requested data in-memory and send them:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <cpprest/http_listener.h>
#include <cpprest/json.h>
#include <cpprest/streams.h>
#include <cpprest/filestream.h>
#include <cpprest/producerconsumerstream.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace concurrency::streams;
using namespace web;
using namespace http;
using namespace http::experimental::listener;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    http_listener listener(L"http://*:8080/bytes");

    listener.support(methods::GET, [](http_request &request) {

        auto q = web::uri::split_query(request.request_uri().query());

        // default: 100 MB of data
        std::size_t bytes_to_write = 100 * 1048576;

        if (q.find(L"b") != std::end(q)) {
            bytes_to_write = std::stoul(q[L"b"]);
        }
        if (q.find(L"kb") != std::end(q)) {
            bytes_to_write = std::stoul(q[L"kb"]) * 1024;
        }
        if (q.find(L"mb") != std::end(q)) {
            bytes_to_write = std::stoul(q[L"mb"]) * 1024 * 1024;
        }

        request.reply(status_codes::OK, std::string(bytes_to_write, '+'));
        std::cout << "Sent " << bytes_to_write << "bytes\n";
    });

    listener.open().wait();

    std::wcout << "Listening on " << listener.uri().port() << std::endl;

    while (true) {
        try {
            Sleep(1);
        }
        catch (...) {
            break;
        }
    }

    listener.close().wait();

    return 0;
}
```

And using curl for testing:

`curl -o NUL http://localhost:8080/bytes?mb=2000`

Using 64Kb chunk size:

```
[root@localhost ~]# curl -o NUL 10.50.10.51:8080/bytes?mb=2000
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 2000M  100 2000M    0     0  15.7M      0  0:02:06  0:02:06 --:--:-- 14.8M
```

Using 5Mb chunck size:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 2000M  100 2000M    0     0  69.2M      0  0:00:28  0:00:28 --:--:-- 77.1M
```

Currently I am modifying the source code of cpprest to get the later result. It's a macro named `CHUNK_SIZE` defined in one of its source files (`http_server_httpsys.cpp`):

```
#define CHUNK_SIZE 64 * 1024
```

Is there an easier way to do this? Or am I using cpprest in the wrong way?

Comment: why not make it a parameter?

Comment: @luke I don't think you can do in any other way. If you want to do, it involves lot of other changes to library which is not a good approach..

Comment: @adam if only I know how to pass the parameter, I would very much not like to change the source code of the library.

Comment: @Prakash I am going to try. Maybe I can replace the implementation with my own...but it means replacing something within a DLL...so the current approach seems lest surprising.